# Job Application Replies

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I submitted a job application and received an email from Stack Overflow saying the submission was successful.

My questions are

- Where can I see my application
- Does the employer reply on this website and , if so, where

Comment: There is nothing in the "sent" folder at all. Can someone from Stack Overflow help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

You weren't logged in when you applied to that job, and then the application wasn't tied to your account (and then, you couldn't see it on Messages).

I checked our logs and I see you actually created the account after applying... so I went ahead and assigned your application to your current account.

You can now follow [Gustav Karlsson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/940731/gustav-karlsson)'s [instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/350486/920295) to see your application.

When an employer replies to you, you'll get an email and their response will also appear in the messages section.

Comment: Could I have missed a reply from them? (BTW - thank you very much for your time!)

Comment: Nope, you couldn't. In the case of anonymous applications, replies from an employer are sent straight to your email. And now that I associated it with your account, you'd see any replies in that thread (even if they were sent before the application was associated with your account)

Answer (score 1):

On the "Jobs" main page, click on the [messages](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages) icon (next to developer story). Your applications can be found in the "Sent" folder.

Replies will similarly end up in the "Applications" inbox.

Comment: There is nothing in the "sent" folder at all. Can someone from Stack Overflow help me with this?